# 35 times increased latency between data send rate of 1 millisecond vs 100 microseconds. WHY?

Tags: command-line-interface, switch, linux-networking, ping, latency

## Experiment

hping -S --data 100 -c 100 10.56.1.2 -i u100 round-trip min/avg/max = 0.5/14.0/15.8 ms

hping -S --data 100 -c 100 10.56.1.2 -i u1000 round-trip min/avg/max = 0.3/0.4/4.8 ms

**Observation**: When the packet send rate increases from 1 millisecond to 100 microseconds the **avg latency increases 35 times** (from .4 to 14) milliseconds

## Experiment setup

Hardware: The source and destination servers are **Supermicro** (http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/6016/SYS-6016TT-IBXF.cfm)

OS: RHEL6

Network: Connected using **HP Procurve** (model 2524 aka J4813A)

IP Addresses: Source server -> 10.56.1.1 and destination server -> 10.56.1.2

Kernel version: 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 on both source and destination.

Network card: Intel® 82576 Dual-Port Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Sysctl settings: no changes from the default

Can you solve this **mystery** ?

Comment: Do you see this when you bypass the switch, i.e. connect the two servers directly together?

Comment: These two servers are in a remote stock exchange data center, it is hard for me to run the experiment bypassing the switch.

Comment: What kernel version are you running? Any special sysctl settings? What NIC devices are you using?

Comment: I edited the original experiment setup section and added the details for 1. Kernel version 2. network card 3. sysctl settings.

Comment: Queuing latency? any packets lost? what about other data arriving?

Comment: Q1) Queuing latency? I do not know how to measure this. Q2) Any packets lost? No Q3) What about other data arriving? None.

Answer (score 0):

This is RHEL6, so you have a lot of options...

Tuning Linux systems for financial trading is a broad topic. I can give you a few tips, but much of this will depend on your environment, application and your equipment.

You haven't changed any `sysctl.conf` settings, so there's a lot to do from that perspective.
Have you monitored server CPU utilization and load while running your test?

Why don't you try a quick change to the two servers to help set a baseline...

Try setting the [**tuned-adm profile**](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuned-adm.html) for the systems to: **latency-performance**

Also disable C-States and power-saving in the BIOS...

[Another good guide to read to get started](http://rhsummit.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/wagner_network_perf.pdf).